# Spring Security @RolesAllowed/@Secured and ROLE_ADMIN

Tags: java, spring-security, roles, rbac

We have an application using *Spring Security* and UI views using *JSR-250*. We use `@RolesAllowed` to give or deny users access to a page based on users' roles. Our requirement is that `ROLE_ADMIN` should always be able to access any view/page but preferably without having to add `ROLE_ADMIN` to all pages using `@RolesAllowed`.

We have come up with two ways to solve this but believe this probably can be handled by *Spring Security* or that there exists some recommended implementation somewhere. It would also be nice with an example or reference to an implementation.

1. Add `ROLE_ADMIN` where user roles are checked so the test always will be true for user `admin`
2. Give all roles to user `admin`

We want alternative 1 if possible.

Where and how can we make *Spring Security* always authorize users with `ROLE_ADMIN` when using `@RolesAllowed` (or even `@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize`/`@PostAuthorize`) with any specified role to restrict access?

Comment: Thanks. I also like the first one the best but I have not found an implementation how to or a best practice. Would like to believe this is something many would want. Second option could maybe be done with [Spring Security RoleHierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437714/spring-security-rolesallowed-secured-and-role-admin) but then I want to do it programatically. That might not be all that easy.

Comment: With [RoleHierarchyImpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#authz-hierarchical-roles), you could create your own factory method to build one using an internal `StringBuilder`. Or you could implement your own `RoleHierarchy` using an `enum`-like set of constants of all your roles.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Even from a properties/yaml or database it seems.